# Rails CPU over 100% After being Deployed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, cpu-usage, nanoboxio

Alright so I have deployed my app via Nanobox and am the last stage. I am using postgresql for my database, Ruby on Rails as my framework, and AWS for our server.

Everything for this app works perfect Locally `localhost:3000`

It appears my CPU Usage with Ruby is Over 100%. Curious as to why... Also while in Production, my migration for `rake db:migrate` was -  Rake aborted!  and am being told to `TOP Task =>  rake db:schema:dump`   (Which I Ran locally prior to production).

Here I will attach a Screenshot of what my apps CPU usage looks like via the nanobox dashboard, as well as some terminal errors.

[image: NanoBox Dashboard of myapp CPU Usage]

[image]

So I am looking to see how to Decrease the CPU % down to a reasonable number because I feel this is the reason as to why I am unable to migrate in production.
Not sure if I should be checking something within my log file / what I should be looking for (over 300k lines) or do I need to increase my packages within AWS / Nanobox. Really looking to have this up and running realatively soon.

Thanks!